# Formula for Azure streaming scaling?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, live-streaming, azure-media-services

Created a web app for live streaming a company meeting.  The web app is trivial - just a banner & an Azure media player.  Trying to figure out a reasonable level & scale out value for my web app and also, the # of streaming units I should add to the Live Streaming endpoint.

Is there a formula anywhere for this kind of thing?  I'll have 6-10,000 users in 4-5 (mostly U.S.) general locations on all kinds of devices.

Answer (score 0):

We need consider a lot of things to scale our web app. This is more related with your requirement. We can set schedule based auto scaling or metrics based auto scaling in Azure web app. We can even define custom scale via use Azure Web APP API.

Comment: Right..Hi-res camera feeding into Azure channel being watched for a short period by avg of 8000 users.

Trying to figure out how many streaming units and how many web apps.  There must be some kind of formula, somewhere, right?   Each streaming unit is 200mbps.  Using Azure Media player to display.  What would you recommend?